# Rewriting Url With .htaccess for Muliple Parameters

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I Want to rewrite the url using .htaccess 
Plz Read the code, and you well Get to know What I mean

My URL :

```
article.php?id=1&title=example
```

***Using this in .htaccess***

```
 RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$
 article.php?id=$1&title=$2 [NC,L]
```

**I get**

```
article/1/example
```

**What i need is**

```
article/example
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ article.php?title=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: gng to try, and let u knw.. thnx for help :)

Comment: in article.php i am running query by getting id from the query string, 
it will not execute with this  article.php?title=$1.

Comment: You asked to remove it if you need it you have to put it in the url

Comment: is there any way, from which i can get title from my database. Both id and title are in same row                                                                                               mysite.com/profile.php?id=23
mysite.com/gorki   Something Like this..